# Modal de Confirmação com codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, modal

Preciso fazer um modal de confirmação de exclusão.

No html

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="Confirmar(<?=$dados->id;?>)">Excluir</a>
```

A funcao

```
<script>
var base_url = '<?php echo base_url() ?>';

function Confirmar(id_registro) {
    bootbox.confirm({
        message: 'Confirma a exclusão do registro?',
        callback: function (confirmacao) {

            if (confirmacao) {
                $.post(base_url + 'index.php/ProspectoCrmController/deletar',{
                    id_registro: id_registro
                }, 'json');
                bootbox.alert('Registro excluído com sucesso.');
            }else {
                bootbox.alert('Operação cancelada.');
            }

        },
        buttons: {
            cancel: {label: 'Cancelar', className: 'btn-default'},
            confirm: {label: 'EXCLUIR', className: 'btn-danger'}

        }
    });
}
```

O que acontece?
o id passado pelo botao de excluir, chega sem erros na função confirmar,
mas no $.post(base_url... não está passando, chega no controller 
mas sem o id

Answer (score 0):

Faça da seguinte maneira:

HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirma-deletar" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Alerta</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Você realmente deseja deletar este registro?</p>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-ok">Sim, quero deletar!</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

BOTÃO DE EXCLUSÃO:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" name="deletar" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirma-deletar" data-href="<? echo base_url("assistenciatecnica/deletando/".$valor->ass_id); ?>" data-id="<?php echo $valor->ass_id; ?>">DELETAR</button></a></button>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('#confirma-deletar').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
});
```

MÉTODO DELETANDO:

```
function deletando($id){
    $retorno = $this->model_implantacao->deletar($id);
    if($retorno==true){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('sucesso', 'Registro deletado com sucesso!');
    }else{
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Erro ao deletar registro!');
    }
    echo redirect(base_url("implantacao"));
}
```

Dessa forma, quando clicar no botão DELETAR, buscará a modal, e com isto, ao clicar em OK ele irá direcionar ao href do botão, chamando o método em questão.

No caso da sua questão, eu faria dessa seguinte forma:

```
if(confirmacao){
    $.ajax({
        type: "json",
        url: base_url + "index.php/ProspectoCrmController/deletar",
        data: {id_registro:id_registro},
        success: function(data){
            bootbox.alert('Registro excluído com sucesso.');
        }
    }); 
} else {
    bootbox.alert('Operação cancelada.');
}
```

**Alterando a parte do if(confirmacao)**

Comment: Ok, assim vai funcionar!

Mas preciso fazer isso funcionar dentro do framework
pra isso no jquery tem chamar o controller (atè ai esta fazendo)
mas tem que levar a variavel junto e nao esta indo...

entao o que voce fez nesse caso nao resolve por nao usar um framework
mas mesmo assim obrigado pela ajuda : )

Comment: Sim, dessa forma, eu uso no codeigniter, mas editei para uma resposta ao seu código, de como eu faria... poste também o deletar do seu controllr

Comment: Saquei... vou testar

Comment: tem alguma estranha no botao.. .ele nao chega no jquery...
chega no modal, mostra a confirmacao e para nao vai para o 
$('#confirma-deletar

Comment: Se ele abriu a modal, ele chamou a função de clique. Onde está errado?

Comment: 1. O Botão
 o botão faz a chamada para o modal:
data-target="#confirma-deletar"

2.O Modal
nessa hora o modal aparece mostrando a opção de cancelar ou "Sim, eu quero deletar"
<div class="modal fade" id="confirma-deletar"

3. A Morte
para tudo ai ele nao chega no jquery
$('#confirma-deletar'
nem na função
function deletando($id)

Answer (score 0):

Opa, boa noite, atualizei minha resposta algumas vezes, vê se te ajuda...

PRIMEIRO DE TUDO, aqui em

```
$.post(base_url + .. bla bla bla
```

não deveria ser

```
$.post(base_url() + bla bla bla ?? faltou o () no base_url() né?
```

Caso não seja isso..

Primeiro, tentando perseguir o erro, coloque alert(id_registro), 
pra ver se recebeu corretamente o parametro, tipo assim, :

```
function Confirmar(id_registro) {
    alert(id_registro);
bootbox.confirm({
```

Em seguida eu tentaria escrever de outra forma, pois as vezes é mais fácil 
que tentar achar o erro.

Tente uma dessas mudanças:

```
<a id='bt-confirma' class="btn btn-primary" onclick="javascript:">Excluir</a>
```

ou

```
<button id='bt-confirma' class="btn btn-primary">Excluir</a>
```

Aí em vez de usar a função faça uso do listener do Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){        
    $('#bt-confirma').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $('#id_registro').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "post", //tenho costume de usar post e alterar o data
            url: base_url('index.php/ProspectoCrmController/deletar') ,
            data: 'id_registro='+id, //sei que parece da idade da pedra, mas...
            success: function(data){
                bootbox.alert('Registro excluído com sucesso.');
            }
        }
    });
});
```